# How to merge two arrays of objects by unique object field via Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to merge two arrays of objects by a unique field via Lodash? 
A small notice: The criteria field is an object as well.

The logic use case explanation:

Basically I have 2 arrays of styles. One is a basic style and the second one is an outer style and right now I just use the simple logic by overriding the Basic by Outer style but I'd like to merge them.

But it isn't so simple because each array item contains the **query** field which is basically a CSS media query expression (React Native, if it matters) and it would be perfect to merge these arrays by Query uniqueness. 
I mean:

- if we have minWidth 200 in both: **Basic** and **Outer** -> carefully merge these styles and the result array should contain the item with the query: `minWith 200` and the style of this query should be merged 2 style items of the **Basic** and **Outer**
- if only one array (Basic or Outer) contains some query, eg. `mingWidth: 500` so we just need to add this query to the resulted array as an independent item.

**Update**: If both arrays (Basic and Outer) contains the same query, the values of the Outer array should override the existing values in the Basic. Unique values should be just merged.

Eg:

```
var Basic= [
      {
       { query: { minWidth: 200 }, 
       { style: { foo: 'bar', color: 'red', } }
      }
    ]

var Outer = [
    {
       { query: { minWidth: 200 }, 
       { style: { color: 'gold', } }
    },
    ]

var Result = [
      {
       { query: { minWidth: 200 }, 
       { style: {  foo: 'bar', color: 'gold', } }
    },
]
```

Please, let me know if some additional information is required.

take a look at the full code example below:

```
var Basic =  [
            {
              query: {minWidth: 50},
              style: {
                color: 'red',
                mode: {
                  'light': {
                    fontSize: 100
                  },
                  'dark': {
                    fontSize: 200
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              query: {minWidth: 100},
              style: {
                width: 2,
                height: 2,
                color: 'white',
                mode: {
                  'light': {
                    backgroundColor: 'zzz',
                  },
                  'dark': {
                    backgroundColor: 'ZZZ',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              query: {minWidth: 200},
              style: {
                width: 5,
                height: 5,
                mode: {
                  'light': {
                    backgroundColor: 'ttt',
                  },
                  'dark': {
                    backgroundColor: 'TTT',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ]

var Outer =  [
            {
              query: {minWidth: 100},
              style: {
                width: 111,
                height: 111,
                fontSize: 15,
                mode: {
                  'light': {
                    backgroundColor: 'nnn',
                  },
                  'dark': {
                    backgroundColor: 'NNN',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              query: {minWidth: 200},
              style: {
                width: 333,
                height: 333,
                opacity: 0,
                mode: {
                  'light': {
                    backgroundColor: 'bbb',
                  },
                  'dark': {
                    backgroundColor: 'BBB',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              query: {minWidth: 900},
              style: {
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
              },
            },
          ]
```

expected result

```
var result = [
            {
              query: {minWidth: 50},
              style: {
                color: 'red',
                mode: {
                  'light': {
                    fontSize: 100
                  },
                  'dark': {
                    fontSize: 200
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              query: {minWidth: 100},
              style: {
                width: 111,
                height: 111,
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: 15,
                mode: {
                  'light': {
                    backgroundColor: 'nnn',
                  },
                  'dark': {
                    backgroundColor: 'NNN',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              query: {minWidth: 200},
              style: {
                width: 333,
                height: 333,
                opacity: 0,
                mode: {
                  'light': {
                    backgroundColor: 'bbb',
                  },
                  'dark': {
                    backgroundColor: 'BBB',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              query: {minWidth: 900},
              style: {
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
              },
            },
          ]
```

Comment: What is the logic you want to follow while merging the two arrays of objects, because its not about simply merging the fields but you're keeping one out of many right ?

Comment: Also with lodash merge, you can merge two objects not two array

Comment: Hi @DJ Yadav. I updated my question and provided the explanation. Thanks for the good notice

Comment: But, its still not clear that if both contain the same query then which one should be picked ?

Also, there is nothing like Basic and Outer in your code.

Comment: Done, also added a small example

Comment: @DJYadav  I made changes you asked for. Do you have any idea how to solve this task?